# Why CSS class isn't applied (using JavaScript onload)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, onload, transition

I'm trying to add class after page is loaded so the transition in added class can change height and opacity of element, but I still can't get it working.

html file:

```
<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function {
      document.getElementById('home-id').className='home-class';
    };
  </script>
</head>
```

css file:

```
#home-id {
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    height: 0.0em;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
html:hover #home-id {
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
.home-class {
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 1.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    height: 40em;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong, thank you.

Edit: I just add that problem wasn't in missing `"()"`, but in specificity.

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/3snbbjmy/

Comment: Yeah, it was a problem with specificity. Works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `classList`:

```
// div is an object reference to a <div> element with class="foo bar"
div.classList.remove("foo");
div.classList.add("anotherclass");

// if visible is set remove it, otherwise add it
div.classList.toggle("visible");

//  add/remove visible, depending on test conditional, i less than 10
div.classList.toggle("visible", i < 10 );

alert(div.classList.contains("foo"));

div.classList.add("foo","bar"); //add multiple classes
```

It gives you more flexibility than using `className` property.

And your function for the `onload` method should be:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('home-id').className='home-class';
};
```

You missed the `()` for `function`.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the support of `.classList`

Comment: Pretty much all browsers support it. IE starting with version 10.

Comment: Except IE 10 doesn't support `.toggle(className, cond);`

Comment: And it also doesn't support multiple values in `add` and `remove` methods.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm learning JavaScript just for several days so I'm not sure if I need to add something else but even after I added "()" to function, it still won't add class after page is loaded. Do I need to somehow wire it to html (put onload function or home-class somewhere into html body)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **jQuery** for this. Simply link the latest version from http://www.code.jquery.com in your HTML file and use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //The following block of code will be executed when the page finishes to load.
   $("#home-id").addClass("home-class"); //This line adds the class "home-class" to the element with the id "home-id"
});
```

If you're not familiar with jQuery I recommend checking out the codecademy jQuery course.(https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery) jQuery is very lightweight, extremely simple to use and learnable with ease.